# Creating maximum limit for max query with groupBy

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this kind of table

```
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | company_id | price |  periods   |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | A1         |   500 | 2016-07-12 |
|  2 | A2         |   540 | 2018-01-21 |
|  3 | A1         |   440 | 2017-01-19 |
|  4 | A2         |   330 | 2016-01-12 |
|  5 | A3         |   333 | 2018-01-22 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
```

and at first i want to just select the maximum `periods` and group them by `company_id` by using this query

```
SELECT salesreport.* FROM salesreport
 INNER JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM salesreport WHERE periods < 2016-01-01 GROUP BY company_id) AS latest_report
       ON salesreport.company_id = latest_report.company_id AND salesreport.periods = latest_report.max_periods;
```

and it will returning table like this

```
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | company_id | price |  periods   |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  2 | A2         |   540 | 2018-01-21 |
|  3 | A1         |   440 | 2017-01-19 |
|  5 | A3         |   333 | 2018-01-22 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
```

but now i want to also make a limit on which maximum periods that i want to get along with grouping so, let say i want `periods <= 2017-01-01` then what i expect is

```
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | company_id | price |  periods   |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | A1         |   500 | 2016-07-12 |
|  4 | A2         |   330 | 2016-01-12 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
```

i tried to use `having` and also the normal `where` but none of them works

```
SELECT salesreport.* FROM salesreport
 INNER JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM salesreport GROUP BY company_id HAVING MAX(periods) < 2017-01-01) AS latest_report
       ON salesreport.company_id = latest_report.company_id AND salesreport.periods = latest_report.max_periods;



SELECT salesreport.* FROM salesreport
 INNER JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM salesreport WHERE periods < 2017-01-01 GROUP BY company_id ) AS latest_report
       ON salesreport.company_id = latest_report.company_id AND salesreport.periods = latest_report.max_periods;
```

and then i realize that maybe because of `MAX(periods)` but how do i get the highest value in groupBy if not using this aggregate? so maybe someone that are expert of query can give a insight to understand and solve this issue....

**Update**

thanks to @Accountant, he create this to help us see and find a solution, feel free to experiment on here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7ae29/31

Comment: Pls show us the result of what you have tried.

Comment: it returned empty, nothing at all...

Comment: Did you see even your "working query" is faulty? You put less than 2016 yet it shows you 2017 and 2018 rows. Pls give us how the table is defined? Is periods column a string or date?

Comment: making `WHERE periods < 2016-01-01` in your first query [will not return anything](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7ae29/2). please recheck the data

Comment: it is Date type and even when i change `where periods < 2018-01-01` it will return empty too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Just get max data only where period is <'2017-01-01'

```
SELECT salesreport.* FROM salesreport
 INNER JOIN 
 (
   SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods 
   FROM salesreport where periods<'2017-01-01'
   GROUP BY company_id

 ) AS latest_report
 ON salesreport.company_id = latest_report.company_id 
 AND salesreport.periods = latest_report.max_periods;
```

Comment: wow that's it so the whole mistake is just because a quotation thank you so much man it just as simple as putting a where

Answer (score 2):

You just missed to put single qoute on the date value. This is working based on sqlfiddle demo by userid: accountant

Correct: MAX(periods) < '2017-01-01'

old:  MAX(periods) < 2017-01-01

Comment: not it is not working, how to get sales report on periods 2016 with those code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sub-query` with *correlated* approach

```
select * from salesreport s
where periods = (select max(periods) from salesreport 
                        where company_id = s.company_id and periods <= '2017-01-01')
```

Comment: care to tell me how to combine it with the whole groupBy situation i am working?

Comment: @LaurensiusTony... Here i have added `periods` filter which was not in your current query. Hence, i have also do that with different approach so that you could find the missing things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compare MAX date, you just need to compare date (periods). Also remove `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT salesreport.* FROM salesreport INNER JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM salesreport WHERE periods < '2017-01-01' GROUP BY company_id) AS latest_report ON salesreport.company_id = latest_report.company_id AND salesreport.periods = latest_report.max_periods
```

Please try this, it should work for you.